# ASP .NET MVC 5 Showing search record in a table without any button click as soon as user start typing in search box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

My current Implementation:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Sorting_Order, string Search_Data)
{
   var modal = _repo.GetAllResturents();
   Search_Data = Search_Data.Trim();
   if (Search_Data != null)
      modal = from r in modal where r.Name.ToUpper().Contains(Search_Data.ToUpper()) select r;
      ViewBag.SortingName = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sorting_Order) ? "Name_Description" : "";
      ViewBag.SortingCity = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sorting_Order) ? "City_Description" : "";

      switch (Sorting_Order)
      {
         case "Name_Description":
            modal = modal.OrderByDescending(nam => nam.Name);
            break;
         case "City_Description":
            modal = modal.OrderByDescending(cit => cit.City);
            break;
         default:
            modal = modal.OrderBy(name => name.Name);
            break;
      }
      return View(modal);
 }
```

Index.cshtml:

```html
<p>
    Search Name: <input type="search" id="search_id" />
    <input type="button"  value="Find" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("index","Resturent")?search_data=' + $('#search_id').val()" />
</p>
```

I want some way so that I can show the records from a database as soon as the user starts typing in the search box. Is it possible using autocomplete or using Ajax ? and what is the best approach for this task.

Note: I am not looking for client-side search.

Comment: You'll definitely need Ajax calls for this. [This post](/q/10318575/3634538) should get you started.

Comment: read about jquery ajax in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use [JQuery DataTable](https://datatables.net/) . Here is complete **GitHub** repository of using [JQuery DataTable With ASP.NET MVC](https://github.com/TanvirArjel/JQueryDataTableWithAspNetMVC)

This will give you lot more along with search record in a table without any button click as soon as user start typing in search box

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to submit each type a button is pressed by Ajax. You can do this using jquery

```
$("#search_id").keyup(function () {
    //call ajax method
});
```

This will submit your data every time the user types a new key